# Offsetting rectangle exposed as property in class

Tags: vb.net, class

I tried the following:

I created a class:

```
Public Class Class1

    Private _MyRect As Rectangle

    Public Property MyRect() As Rectangle
        Get
            Return _MyRect
        End Get
        Set(value As Rectangle)
            _MyRect = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then I instantiated the class and its rectangle like this in a form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim c As New Class1
        Dim r As Rectangle = Rectangle.FromLTRB(10, 10, 50, 50)
        c.MyRect = r

        c.MyRect.Offset(100, 100)
        Debug.Print(c.MyRect.ToString)

    End Sub
End Class
```

The debug string tells me that the offsetting had no effect.

What is going on here, and how would I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `Rectangle` is a value type so this line:

```
c.MyRect.Offset(100, 100)
```

is actually acting on a copy of the value contained in your `Class1` object.  If you call `Offset` on `r` before assigning to `c.MyRect` then it will work.  If you want to be able to make the change after the initial assignment then you need to get the property value, assign it to a variable, call `Offset`, then assign back to the property:

```
Dim r1 = c.MyRect

r1.Offset(100, 100)
c.MyRect = r1

Debug.Print(c.MyRect.ToString)
```

Note that, if `Rectangle` was a class rather than a structure then your existing code would work as expected.  This is the important difference between value types and reference types that catches many people out.